# Why is insertAdjacentHTML converting HTML into an object

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Compiling a directive for injection but inserting it into the DOM is not working. Any ideas?

`_testHeader = $compile(ABHeaderTemplate)($scope);`

`_testHeader` now equals `[<header class="ng-scope">..</header>]`

Grab the index so it's not an array.

`_testHeader[0]` returns `<header class="ng-scope">..</header>`

Then trying to insert it into DOM

`document.body.children[0].insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", _testHeader[0]);`

returns `"[object HTMLElement]"`

I've tried using append (to no avail) and I'm compiling the template on load and triggering the appending through an event. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: The `insertAdjacentHTML()` function expects you to pass it a **string**. You're passing it a DOM node.

Comment: When I use toString() I get the same error back as a String.

Comment: Of course - when you call `.toString()` on a DOM node you get that string. I think you probably need to `.append()` the node or something.

Comment: should be `document.body.children[0].insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", _testHeader[0].innerHTML);`

Comment: That worked Pankaj! Please post as an Answer.

Comment: Welp there you go :) *edit* actually that'll insert the contents of the `<header>` but not the header tag itself, no?

Comment: @Pointy Yes, that's correct! dfsq's answer worked as intended (will accept after timer).  But I'd upvote Pankaj's as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[insertAdjacentHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) inserts HTML string. You need [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) or in your case [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore) since you want to prepend new content into body:

```
document.body.insertBefore(_testHeader[0], document.body.children[0]);
```